# Generate a unique ID C++

Tags: c++, struct, identifier

I want to generate a unique identifier "ident" for my complex structure, how can i do that?

in my header, the complexe structure is:

```
struct Complexe {
    float x;
    float y;
    static unsigned int ident;
};

void Init(Complexe&);

etc...
```

and in the cpp file, i need to attribute ident a unique int

```
Init(Complexe&z){
    z.ident = 0;
    z.y = 0;
    z.x = 0;
};
```

Comment: Use `0` (or `1`) for the first ident, `1` for the next and so on. If your program doesn't run millions of times per second you'll be good for a few thousand years.

Comment: Unrelated: use `double` for floating-point variables (unless you're aiming for severely restricted environments); forget `float` exists.

Comment: Unrelated: C has had complex numbers as part of the language for more than 20 years. Think of `#include <complex.h>`?

Comment: Thanks, i'm using float because it's requested in the school work and they want us to manipulate complexe using struct  for now and not the #include <complex.h>

Comment: thanks it worked with:  `void Init(Complexe&z){
    static unsigned int id = 0;
    z.ident = id++;
    z.y = 0;
    z.x = 0;
};`

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend you [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)?

`std::size_t ident = std::hash<Complex>()(complexVar);`

Writing it from memory but it should return you unique value (with very small chance of it being not) for each `Complex` type object.

Answer (score 1):

Consider UUID, specifically uuid_generate on GNU/Linux, or (it seems) UuidCreate on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Generating a unique id is easy even if you want to write your own algorithm. Though your algorithm will need some thoughts if the environment you are working in is multi-threaded. In this case you will need to write a thread safe code. for example below code will generate a unique id and is also thread safe:

```
class Utility {
public :
    static int getUniqueId();
};

int Utility::getUniqueId() {
    static std::atomic<std::uint32_t> uid { 0 };
    return ++uid;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an explicit `fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)`, since you don't actually need or want synchronization, just atomicity.

Comment: @Hasturkun , thanks for the food for thought. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to just make a free-list to help you reuse IDs. So for instance you start at ID 0 and whenever you create a structure, you first check the free-list for any released IDs. It will be empty the first time through so you increment the ID counter to 1 and use that for your new structure. When you destroy a structure it's ID goes back on the free-list (which can be implemented as a stack), so that the next time you create a structure that ID will be reused. If the free-list runs out of IDs you just start incrementing the ID counter from where you left off....wash, rinse and repeat. The nice thing about this method is that you will never wrap integer range and accidentally use an already in use ID if your program ends up running a long time.  The main down side is the extra storage for the stack, but the stack can always grow as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to generate unique identifiers that transcend space and time, you might want to check out [boost's uuid sublibrary](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/uuid/doc/uuid.html).
This library is a treasure trove of tools and features that make working with uuids a breeze.

The following code snippet shows how you can create a new uuid and display its cosmic beauty to `std::cout`.

To compile this code on MinGW64 on Windows 11, you need to invoke the following command (I havent linux machine):

`g++ main.cpp -lBcrypt`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/uuid/uuid.hpp"
#include "boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp"
#include "boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp" // for streaming operators

// A function that returns a new uuid from the boost::uuids::random_generator
boost::uuids::uuid NewUUID() noexcept
{
    auto uuid{boost::uuids::random_generator{}()};
    return uuid;
}

int main()
{
    auto uuid{NewUUID()}; 
    std::cout << uuid << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

**sample output**:

```bash
...>a.exe
6d4b65e9-3ed3-4b56-9936-2ef345c48569
```

This output shows one possible uuid that was generated by the code. Each time you run the program, you will get a different uuid that is unique in the multiverse.

### Note for `boost.uuid`

I have boost 1.82 installed on my machine. If you have configured boost correctly, you don't need to link any library statically / dynamically.